# How to transform source image to destination image automatically using opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6yTc.jpg)
I am having source image on the left. I distorted this image manually using grids from paint and result is on the right side. I was wondering if opencv offers any function which compares both images and gives some transformation matrix which I can use for further use. e.g. Passing this matrix to the video and I have distorted video like the image on right side.

I appreciate the help of this community :)

Comment: You should use a feature matcher (https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html) but instead of a black and white grid, use a grid where each square is a different shade of gray.

Comment: thank you I will try this way. Still, if I get the values of vectors, how I can pass this to video to distort it?

Answer (score 0):

***I was wondering if opencv offers any function which compares both images and gives some transformation matrix which I can use for further use.***

Neither OpenCV nor any other library can calculate transformation matrix for non-linear transformation. It is impossible to represent non-linear transformation as a transformation matrix. However, one may find a transformation matrix that will be linear approximation of non-linear transformation. Such approximations should not necessarily yield satisfactory results.
As the image that you distort has a check pattern, you may describe the distortion by the movement of the corners of squares. I suggest that you try the following two-step approach:

**Step1: Find corners both in original and distorted images.**
OpenCV has a bunch of functions that are used in camera calibration and are designed for check pattern images. The following function uses [cv2.findChessboardCorners](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga93efa9b0aa890de240ca32b11253dd4a) function from OpenCV to find the corner points. Note: `get_chessboard_corner_points` returns relative coordinates, not the exact ones.

```
def get_chessboard_corner_points(img, corner_shape=(10,15)):
    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.01)
    success, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(img, corner_shape)
    if success:
        corners = cv2.cornerSubPix(img, corners, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria)
        corners = np.squeeze(corners, axis=1)
        for i in range(len(corners)):
            corners[i] = (corners[i][0]/img.shape[1], corners[i][1]/img.shape[0])
        #You may also try adding boundary points of the image by uncommenting the next line.
        #corners = np.append(corners, np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]), 0)
        #In addition you may also add other boundary points acording to your needs
        return corners
    return []
```

**Step2: Distort each frame of video using interpolation and points found in the previous step.**
Now when you have the points you need to write the distortion part.The `distort_image` function will do the job, though you may change it according to your needs. Note: `src` and `dest` contain relative coordinates. For target image we calculate and keep the exact coordinates in `src_exact` and `dest_exact` respectively. Then, [griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) from [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/index.html) is being used for interpolation.

```
def distort_image(img, src, dest):
    height, width = img.shape[:2]
    src_exact = []
    dest_exact = []
    for i in range(len(src)):
        src_exact.append((int(src[i][1]*height), int(src[i][0]*width)))
        dest_exact.append((int(dest[i][1]*height), int(dest[i][0]*width)))
    grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:height - 1:complex(0, height), 0:width - 1:complex(0, width)]
    grid_z = griddata(dest_exact, src_exact, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')
    map_x = np.append([], [ar[:, 1] for ar in grid_z]).reshape(height, width)
    map_y = np.append([], [ar[:, 0] for ar in grid_z]).reshape(height, width)
    map_x_32 = map_x.astype('float32')
    map_y_32 = map_y.astype('float32')
    distorted = cv2.remap(img, map_x_32, map_y_32, cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    return distorted
```

And here are a few lines that allow you to test the above presented functions.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

TEST_IMG_PATH = "" #path to original grid 
SOURCE_IMG_PATH = "" #path to distorted grid 
DEST_IMG_PATH = "" #path to image to be distorted(this can be replaced by a video frame)
CORNER_SHAPE = (10, 15)

src_img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(SOURCE_IMG_PATH), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
dest_img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(DEST_IMG_PATH), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
test = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(TEST_IMG_PATH), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
src_points = get_chessboard_corner_points(src_img, CORNER_SHAPE)
dest_points = get_chessboard_corner_points(dest_img, CORNER_SHAPE)
if len(src_points) != 0 and len(dest_points) != 0:  
    result = distort_image(test, src_points, dest_points)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.